# Java File runs in eclipse but on command line

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I have created a jar file in eclipse using maven and am able to run a class from the jar file with eclipse. However when I run the following command from the command prompt:

```
c:\recomendation_engine\recomendation\target>java -classpath recomendation-0.0.1
-SNAPSHOT.jar recomendation.ManageGeneralContent test
```

I get the following error:

```
Organization Environment test
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at recomendation.ManageGeneralContent.main(ManageGeneralContent.java:52)
```

I believe that the issue is that the class can not find the mysql driver. However it is in the classpath:

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\lib\*;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\google\
guava\guava\18.0-rc1\guava-18.0-rc1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\s
lf4j-api\1.7.7\slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\jolbox\bonec
p\0.8.0.RELEASE\bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\postgresql
\postgresql\9.1-901-1.jdbc4\postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar;c:\recomendation_engi
ne\recomendation\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar;C:\recomendation_engine\reco
mendation\target\recomendation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Since Java 6, it has not been necessary to load JDBC drivers with Class.forName.  Simply placing the driver in the classpath is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the **CLASSPATH** environment variable when you specify the "-classpath" switch on the java command line.

Try running:

```
c:\recomendation_engine\recomendation\target>java 
    recomendation.ManageGeneralContent test
```

Check out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html

Comment: Awesome! If you like, please take a moment to give my answer the checkmark.